What am I doing wrong solving $\iint_{S} (5x + 2y + z^2)dS$
I want to solve $\iint_{S}^{} (5x + 2y + z^2)dS$ where $S$ is a sphere of radius $3$ centered at the origin. The first way I can solve it is with the divergence theorem, where
$$\iint_{S}(5x+2y+z^2)dS = \iint_{S}\langle5, 2, z\rangle \cdot \langle x,y,z \rangle dS=\iiint_{E}\text{div}(\vec{F})\space dV $$.
Since $E$ is the ball of radius 3, and $\operatorname{div} \vec{F} = 1$, then the surface integral is just the volume of the ball, $\frac{4}{3}\pi (3)^3 = 36\pi$
However, when I try to solve with integral directly by parameterizing S as:
$$\vec{r}(\phi, \theta)= \langle3\sin(\phi)\cos(\theta), 3\sin(\phi)\sin(\theta), 3\cos(\phi) \rangle$$
Then $$|\vec{r_{\phi}} \times \vec{r_{\theta}}|=R^2|\sin(\phi)|, \space R=3$$
So
$$\iint_{S} (5x + 2y + z^2)dS=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\!\!\!\int_{0}^{\pi} (15\sin(\phi)\cos(\theta) + 6\sin(\phi)\sin(\theta) + 9\cos^2(\phi))(9\sin(\phi))d\phi\theta=36\pi\cdot 3$$
The second integral is $3$ times the first! Which one is correct, if either, and where am I going wrong in one of them? Thank you!

Your error is in the first approach: you need to use the outward unit normal in the divergence theorem.
The divergence theorem gives $\int F \cdot \hat n\,\mathrm dS = \iiint \nabla\cdot F\,\mathrm dV$, here $n$ is the outward unit normal. In your case the unit normal is $\hat n$ is  $(x,y,z)/\|(x,y,z)\|= (x,y,z)/3$. Therefore,
$$ \iint (5x+2y+z^2)\,\mathrm  dS = \iint 3~ (5,2,z)\cdot\hat n\,\mathrm  dS = \iiint 3\,\mathrm dV=3\times \frac{4 \pi 27}{3}=108 \pi.$$
There's an easier way to solve this.  By symmetry, $\iint x\,\mathrm dS = \iint y\,\mathrm dS = 0$ and $\iint z^2\,\mathrm dS = \iint y^2\,\mathrm dS = \iint x^2\,\mathrm dS$. Therefore the desired integral is equal to
$$\frac 13 \iint (x^2+ y^2+ z^2 )\,\mathrm dS = 3 \iint\,\mathrm dS = 3 \times 4 \pi 9 =108 \pi.$$

Ah ok thank you

Unfortunately, the first approach is what I used on a test today :(
